# xecjk: Only the last FontFace worked

Tags: fontspec, xecjk

I tried to use Noto Serif CJK TC, which contains 7 font weights,  as CJK main font. I defined the font face with:

```
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK TC}[
    FontFace={el}{n}{* ExtraLight},
    FontFace={l}{n}{* Light},
    FontFace={sb}{n}{* SemiBold},
    FontFace={b}{n}{* Bold},
    FontFace={eb}{n}{* Black}
]
```

Nevertheless, it seems that only the last FontFace worked.

[image: Imgur]

As the photo  shows, only Black display properly. When I remove  `FontFace={eb}{n}{* Black}`, now  Bold become correct.

[image: Imgur]

Therefore, how can I have all FontFace present without any error?

Thanks.

*edit: [example tex file](https://gist.github.com/nevikw39/217640bdf106d8464124af90015292ee)*

Comment: Show a complete example, don't let us guess how you try to access the fonts. And say also which latex version you are using - they have been changes in this area lately.

Comment: I'm using XeLaTeX.

Here is the [example](https://gist.github.com/nevikw39/217640bdf106d8464124af90015292ee).

Comment: I meant which latex version. Check the log-file, there should be a line starting with LaTeX2e and a date: `LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5`. And copy the example in your questions. Links are not stable.

Comment: The version is *LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>*, which installed from apt today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally solved my problem.

Thanks @ulrike-fischer for inspiration, I found my TeX Live installed from apt is outdated.

After removing the old TeX Live and installing the latest, everything works so fine.

[image: img]